# SharePoint: Get value(s) from MultiChoice field programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, field

I am copying several fields' values from one list item to another. If I simply call `ToString()` on the MultiChoice field I get a value like `;#Value;#` which is obviously not the value I want to copy. The target item has a value of `Text`, so I simply wish to copy the values into an array, join with ", " so I get a nice textual representation.

How do I get the "real" value(s) from the field? The class type of the field is `SPFieldMultiChoice`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a class called SPFieldMultiChoiceValue. Initialize it with with field value and you will have a collection of specific selected option. Then you convert this collection into a string of your liking.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415672.aspx